# Method that gets URl of page with selenium in object - gets error

Tags: python, selenium, oop

I made a "page" class so I can use it for calling webdriver(among other stuff), and making in execute commands in more OOP structured way. However I encounter error that "webdriver object is not callable" with first method, which should get URL of page object.

Code:

```
class Page():
    def __init__(self, url, webdriver):
        self.url = url
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def get_page(self):
        self.driver(self.url)
```

initialisation of class:

```
from klase import Page
from selenium import webdriver

global webdriver

url = "www.somepage.com"
stranica = Page(url, webdriver)
stranica.get_page()
```

And error :

> File "C:/Users/Costello/PycharmProjects/ItallyBetting/test.py", line
>   8, in 
>       stranica.get_page()   File "C:\Users\Costello\PycharmProjects\ItallyBetting\klase.py", line 27,
>   in get_page
>       self.driver(self.url) TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not callable

what does this even mean and how can I fix it?

thank you in advance.

p.s.

I tried out this:

```
def get_page(self,  self.url, self.driver):
    self.driver(self.url)
```

Figured out i need to add arguments. I guess its something with scopes in side a class but cant figure out what... please help :)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED IT!

silly me i forget to call method .get() on the driver. So it should lookedl ike this:

```
def get_page(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)
```

Comment: Make sure you come back and accept this as the answer so that the question doesn't get left unanswered.